# Dataset database

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have problem to visit [dataset](http://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) page,

if you have deal with this tool

for example if I want delete some row with "y" equal value:

```
table.delete(Text=y)
```

so useful way as any other to delete specific row.

if I want delete one with all exist rows equal 'phrase':

```
table.delete(Text='phrase')
```

but how to delete everything, just all rows in database at once to zero?

and also if I want make it avalibele for other user by paht C:\ProgramData\data_folder this way:

```
mypath = os.path.join(os.getenv('programdata'), data_folder')
```

how to do same with:

```
db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///mydatabase.db')
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about; is it [this `dataset` project](http://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) perhaps?

Comment: problem is that I  can not open this website for the week and still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete *all* rows, just call `table.delete()` with no arguments.

From the [`dataset.Table.delete()` documentation](http://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#dataset.Table.delete):

> If no arguments are given, all records are deleted.

If you need your database to be stored in a specific location, you can just put the full path into the connection argument for the `dataset.connect()`, after `sqlite:///`:

```
mypath = os.path.join(os.getenv('programdata'), 'data_folder', 'mydatabase.db')
db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///' + mypath)
```

See the [Database URLs documentation for SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html#sqlite).

Comment: hello, 

what I'm doing wrong? 

because this way, in both cases, if I got  mypath: 

`mypath = os.path.join(os.getenv('programdata'), 'database.db') `

with 

`db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///' + mypath)

table = db['user']`

or with other variables I got this error, I have added it above

Comment: @Ai_ve: it means the directory in which you want to place the database either doesn't exist or cannot be written to.

Comment: yes but it is exist        `if not os.path.isdir(mypath):
            os.makedirs(mypath)`

Comment: @Ai_ve: but can the user write to that directory? When you search for `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file` on Google you'll find a wide range of questions and answers about the subject.